# Auto renewable IAP subscription user flow & refreshing receipts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I am using the library [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) - here's what I have currently.

1) Purchase auto renewable subscription & verify the returned receipt.

```
[[RMStore defaultStore]addPayment:[Environment environment].premiumProductIAPId success:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
  [[RMStore defaultStore].receiptVerificator verifyTransaction:transaction success:^{

    //enable premium service

  } failure:^(NSError *error) {

  }];
} failure:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction, NSError *error) {

}];
```

2) On each app launch check the subscription is active for the date and enable the premium service if it is

```
RMAppReceipt *appReceipt = [RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt];
if (appReceipt){
  NSInteger isActive = [appReceipt containsActiveAutoRenewableSubscriptionOfProductIdentifier:[Environment environment].premiumProductIAPId forDate:[NSDate date]];
  //enable premium service if active
}
```

3) If user launches app on another device allow them to restore purchases by refreshing the receipt if it exists and checking if there is an active subscription in the purchases.

```
"In most cases, all your app needs to do is refresh its receipt and deliver the products in its receipt."
```

- That's from the guide. Here's the code:

```
[[RMStore defaultStore]refreshReceiptOnSuccess:^{

  if ([receipt containsActiveAutoRenewableSubscriptionOfProductIdentifier:[Environment environment].premiumProductIAPId forDate:[NSDate date]]){
   //enable
  }else{ 
   //no longer active
  }
} failure:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

My questions:

- When RMStore checks if the subscription is active it can return no, I look in the receipt and it is correct and I am assuming it hasn't been auto renewed. When I go to purchase another subscription I get a message from itunes saying I'm already subscribed. On subsequent launch I see the new receipt. This indicates the receipt needed to be refreshed on launch, but I don't want to refresh it as it brings up the username & password pop up which is unnecessary. What is the best practice here?
- Am I restoring the subscriptions for another device the right way? It seems to sometimes take more than one attempt to restore the subscriptions.
- Is there any need apart from record keeping to store the subscriptions on my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer my question.

There may be a renewal which is not detected first thing on launch hence the subscription appears inactive.

I added an observer to listen for finished transactions (RMStore extends this StoreKit functionality).

Each time I receive this notification I check the (now updated) receipt for an active subscription and enable the premium service if there is one.

```
- (void)storePaymentTransactionFinished:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  BOOL isActive = [[RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt] containsActiveAutoRenewableSubscriptionOfProductIdentifier:[Environment environment].premiumProductIAPId forDate:[NSDate date]];
  if (isActive){
    //enable premium
  }
}
```

This seems to be working. If anyone has any other suggestions let me know.

Comment: I have a query what will happen to the main receipt when he cancels and activates the subscription again? Whether new receipt will be generated or what will happen?

Comment: @Yohan I think you'll receive a notification next time the person launches the app which will trigger the above method.